# Convert a timestamp into excel readable format?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to convert a column in my excel sheet which has the value like:
Jan 31 2016 11:41PM, 
I need to convert it into excel readable format like:
1/31/2016  11:41:00 PM.

I tried to convert by reformatting the column in excel and several other alternatives but doesn't work.

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: Did either of the answers work for you? If so then please mark one as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),FIND("}}}",(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",2)))-FIND(" ",A1))) &" " & LEFT(A1,3) & MID(A1,FIND("}}}",(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",2))),LEN(A1)),"P"," P"),"A", " A")
```

[image]

Then using a custom Format of:

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM
```

[image]

you get a number disguised as a date time:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"PM"," PM"),"AM"," AM")," ",", ",2)
```

the output is a datetime value.

Then format it using number formatting to your liking.

> here is a break down view of the formula
>   [image]